# Including non-java files when compiling into WAR using Maven

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml, war

I am working on a Spring Boot web application that accesses an IBM cloud service. In order for the service API to work, an IBM-credentials.env file must be located at the root of the project (where pom.xml is located). How can I include this file when packaging into WAR with Maven?

I've tried adding :

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>/</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>ibm-credentials.env</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

but all that did was *exclude* application.properties.

Comment: You probably don't want it at the root of the project, but at the root of the resulting WAR, right?

Comment: @JFMeier Yes. I believe so. I think it should be in WEB-INF I'm not exactly sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Apache Maven Assembly Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) to create war file. Create an assembly descriptor which contains structure, format and files to include and exclude.

Answer (score 0):

below configuration worked for me, if it's not including your property file then add them in includes

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>Source Folder 1relative  path</directory>
                <targetPath>Target path in war</targetPath>
            </resource>

            <resource>
                <directory>Source Folder 2 relative path</directory>
                <targetPath>Target path in war</targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.extention</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>

        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```